# Why is nginx-ingress-controller config different in different clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I use pathType: ImplementationSpecific  for many routes in an ingress.

The final nginx-ingress-controller configs for two clusters:

```
location ~* /some/route/(?!one|two|three).{1,} # one cluster
location /some/route/(?!one|two|three).{1,} # other cluster
```

The second one is wrong because it is a regex route but ~* is missing.

The nginx-ingress-controller versions are matching in both environments.
The use-regex annotation is NOT used in any of the environments.
From the docs I read that ImplementationSpecific depends on the ingress class and I am not sure what that means.
I didn't find any configuration that could explain this behaviour and difference between the configs.

Why is nginx-ingress-controller config different in different clusters?

Answer (score 1):

The nginx-ingress-controller config depends on the cluster.

When running NGINX Ingress Controller, you have the following options with regards to which configuration resources it handles:

**Cluster-wide Ingress Controller (default)**. The Ingress Controller handles configuration resources created in any namespace of the cluster. As NGINX is a high-performance load balancer capable of serving many applications at the same time, this option is used by default in our installation manifests and Helm chart.

**Single-namespace Ingress Controller**. You can configure the Ingress Controller to handle configuration resources only from a particular namespace, which is controlled through the -watch-namespace command-line argument. This can be useful if you want to use different NGINX Ingress Controllers for different applications, both in terms of isolation and/or operation.

**Ingress Controller for Specific Ingress Class**. This option works in conjunction with either of the options above. You can further customize which configuration resources are handled by the Ingress Controller by configuring the class of the Ingress Controller and using that class in your configuration resources. See the section Configuring Ingress Class.

For more information refer to this [document](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/running-multiple-ingress-controllers/).

Some use cases for this might be:
An Ingress Controller that is behind an internal ELB for traffic between services within the VPC (or a group of peered VPCs)

- An Ingress Controller behind an ELB that already terminates SSL

An Ingress Controller with different functionality or performance

Most NGINX configuration options have NGINX-wide defaults. They can
also be overridden on a per-Ingress resource level.

For more information refer to this [document](https://docs.giantswarm.io/advanced/ingress/multi-nginx-ic/).